# Uninstall Flink on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation, apache-flink

ubuntu newbie here.
Some days ago I installed Flink version 1.3.1 on a ubuntu cluster.
I absolutely need the last version 1.3.2 but I don't find any procedure on google to safely uninstall flink. I have no applications builded but I want be sure I will have no leftovers.

Delete the folder is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can just delete the Flink folder. While there may be some temporary files (under /tmp or whatever you're configured tmp dir is), these are not essential and will not affect other installations.